# draw graph with igraph or networkx with dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, igraph

How can I draw graph with igraph or networkx with my_data in python?

```
my_data = [
  {
    'title': 'title1', 'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
  },
  {
    'title': 'title2', 'tags': ['tag1']
  }
]
```

Comment: No,it doesn't @ThomasIsCoding

Comment: what kind of graph do you want to draw? Could you show how it looks like?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding I want to import a file into gephi software  and I think I should  use networkx or igraph packages before that But I don't know how can use these packages

Comment: @Zephyr No one has answered that question